# Webpack2 Hot Module Reloading a Express.js Universal React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-2

The webpack config of a universal app usually is an array of config objects like:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: 'client',
        entry: {
            app: [...require("./loaders").hotLoaders, "./src/frontend/client"],
            libs: [
                'react', 'react-dom'
            ]
        },
        output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../../www"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js"
        }, 
     ...
    },
    {
        name: 'server',
        target: 'node',
        entry: {
            server: ["./src/universal/server"],
            express: ["./src/universal/express"]
        },
        output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../../www"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js"
        }  
        ...   
    }];
```

After running `webpack --config build/webpack/prod.js`, I can do the following on production, just run the output of server.express chunk like `node www/express.bundle.js`.

```
//  src/universal/express.tsx 
import SERVER from "./server"
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('www'));
app.use(require("morgan")('combined'));
app.use(SERVER);
app.listen(3000);
```

And for development I can `node hot.js` and I get HMR working nice.

```
// hot.js
const app = require("express")();
const compiler = require('webpack')(require('./build/webpack/prod.js'));
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler);
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler.compilers.find(compiler => compiler.name === 'client')));
app.use(require("morgan")('combined'));
app.use(require("./www/server.bundle").default);
app.listen(3000);
```

HMR works very fast like this. But as soon as I start editing my files, react shows me warning about `React attempted to reuse markup`. When the code changes, hmr does its magic but the server keep sending the old markup even with a hard refresh because I am hard requiring a bundle file like `let SERVER = require("./www/server.bundle").default;` Maybe webpack-dev-server handles this, but how do I setup it with an array of webpack config?

I thought of making hot.js a chunk as well, but it calls `require('./build/webpack/prod.js')` that calls `require('webpack')` a lot, making webpack angry and not compiling anything.

Comment: can you share your package.json & webpackconfig i am looking for same

Comment: https://github.com/cescoferraro/spotify @AnilGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [`webpack-hot-server-middleware`](https://github.com/60frames/webpack-hot-server-middleware) which was designed to solve this very problem.

All you'd need to do is replace the hardcoded `require('./www/server.bundle').default` with `webpack-hot-server-middleware`, e.g.

```
const app = require("express")();
const compiler = require('webpack')(require('./build/webpack/prod.js'));
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler);
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler.compilers.find(compiler => compiler.name === 'client')));
app.use(require("morgan")('combined'));
app.use(require('webpack-hot-server-middleware')(compiler, { chunkName: 'server' });
app.listen(3000);
```

Webpack Hot Server Middleware will then make sure each request is passed to the most recent compilation of `server.bundle.js` so you no longer have to restart your server during development.

Additionally, it has the added benefit of sharing the same Webpack cache as the client bundle for faster builds.